# XSL 1.0 find max value from nodes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, xslt-1.0

I want to get the Max value from nodes

Here is my XML:

```
    <xml>
     <NewDataSet>
        <priorityResult>
            <DXCount>32</DXCount>
            <LHHight>12</LHHight>
            <LHMedium>1</LHMedium>
            <RiskPriority>6</RiskPriority>
        </priorityResult>
    </NewDataSet>
   </xml>
```

I want to display a value in XSLT page using this functionality:

```
 var priority= parseInt(row["RiskPriority"]);
 var newPriority= 0;

if ("DXCount" > 0 )
newPriority= 4;
else if ("LHHigh" > 0)
newPriority= 3;
else if ("LHMedium" > 0)
newPriority= 2;

return Math.max(priority, newPriority)
```

How do I get this max value using xslt?

I tried this to display the Node values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">    
<xsl:for-each select="//priorityResult[SessionID != '']">
            <p>
              Priority :
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="DXCount > 0">
                    4
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="LHHigh > 0">
                    3
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="LHMedium > 0">
                    2
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select ="RiskPriority"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </p>
          </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 has no `max()` function. If I understand your logic correctly, you could implement it in XSLT 1.0 as:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/xml">    
    <xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/priorityResult">
        <xsl:variable name="newPriority">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="DXCount > 0">4</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="LHHigh > 0">3</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="LHMedium > 0">2</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <p>
            <xsl:text>Priority :</xsl:text>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="RiskPriority > $newPriority">
                    <xsl:value-of select ="RiskPriority"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select ="$newPriority"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This solution worked just fine for me. Thank you so much